# Interpretation of "по одному"

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

What is the function of *по одному* in the following sentence?

> Брежнев ехал на машине по одному из московских проспектов

I did some research and [apparently](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83) it means **one at a time**, that doesn't really make sense here, however.

Isn't it better to just use something like *по улице* in this case?

Comment: by the way, hyphen must not be used here. it's misleading.

Comment: There is *по одному из проспектов* (*along one of the roads*, as Vadim mentioned), not *на машине по одному*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing two completely different cases here:

1. **брал предметы по одному** - took the items **one at a time**. Here, "по одному" is an adverb;
2. **ехал по одному из проспектов** - drove along **one of the** roads. In this case, "один из проспектов" is the object.

Comment: There's no such word class as "object ".